# HTTP 403 Forbidden Message Format

Tags: http, http-headers

What is the correct format for sending an HTTP 403 forbidden message?

I'm writing a proxy in c for a homework project that has a content filtering system built in. When my proxy detects that a server's response has certain keywords that are contained in the content blacklist, I would like to send a HTTP 403 Forbidden message.

Currently, I am sending the message as: "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\r\n\r\n" (without the quotes) as per this standard: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3

When I send this message, the browser doesn't display an error and looks like it's still trying to load the page.

Are there any required header fields for this http message that I missed? Also, is this the correct usage for the 403 error? I couldn't find anything else that would be more fitting, so I chose 403 because the client won't automatically re-request the data.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Usually 400 might be more useful, since it’s about the request being invalid, not about authorization missing. Do you disconnect the socket after that?

Comment: Oops, ya I forgot to close the socket. Thanks for that. The browser currently displays a blank screen after it receives the 400. I thought that the html generated from errors was dependent on the browser. Is this correct? Or is the sender required to send html that goes along with the error?

Comment: You can send HTML with the error, the browser can show it or not. Some prefer their own message. Also you can send a `Connection: close` header if you are using HTTP/1.1 to tell the browser you’re done with them, but closing the socket after a valid response is also enough

Comment: Great, thank you for your help!

Comment: So should you answer your own question so people with a similar problems will know what to do? Resful use of the HTTP codes here: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/amazon-drive/ad-restful-api-response-codes.html but I don't recall it being standard (more like a convention the resful APIs use the HTTP codes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those struggling with this issue as I did, you need to make sure to close the socket or set `Connection: Close` as Sami noted in the comments. I assumed that you could keep it open so they could send another request with http persistent connections, but they will need to open a new connection.

As for the html displayed, you can send a body with the response (make sure you set Content-Length) that contains the html you want displayed.

Finally, here are two references, one to the HTTP response spec, and the other to the Amazon Restful response spec:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/amazon-drive/ad-restful-api-response-codes.html